# Simple AJAX seems to quietly overwhelm browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I have  a small AJAX,  within a recursive function, and a `setTimeout` on `complete`.  Since I have implemented this, I have clients complaining about lag after a few hours of sitting on the page...

```
get_activity();

function get_activity() {
    var activity = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/activity.php",
        async: false
    }).complete(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            get_activity();
        }, 5000);
    }).responseText;

    $('#activity').html(activity);
}
```

Being that it's in a callback, `.complete` and that it's on a `setTimeout` of 5 seconds, I thought it would be safe to run.  The response is nothing more than a table with exactly 1,000 rows *(based on `LIMIT` in `mysql` call)* and 3 columns.  Nothing huge:

```
<table style="font-size:9px; width:100%; font-weight:bold; color:#FFF;">
<?php foreach ($activity_log as $item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:60px;">
            <?= $item['user'] ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width:120px;">
            <?= $item['activity'] ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width:100px;">
            <?= date('M j, Y G:i', strtotime($item['date_completed'])); ?>
       </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

If you notice in my AJAX I am using

```
$('#activity').html(activity);
```

vs

```
$('#activity').append(activity);
```

So `$('#activity')`s DOM element is being overwritten every time.  So I know I am not loading the browser up that way.

I feel that I am doing everything right --  Not loading up the requests, effectively making them synchronous --  And I am not loading up the DOM, rather I am clearing and filling the `div` with each request.

Does anyone see a reason this script and it's response would cause both Chrome and FF to load up and lag after a few hours on the page?

Comment: `async: false` <-- bad... do not use synchronous calls. That is why you can have issues

Comment: Sounds like something isn't being garbage-collected. What does the memory profiler show?

Comment: There's no need to make this synchronous. Put the `.html()` call in the `.complete()` function.

Comment: @epascarello -- So I understood the documentation wrong --  My assumption was that `async: false` would ensure that the function could not run parallel to itself? I am mistaken?

Comment: It locks up the browser to make the call

Comment: As an aside to this, AJAX polling is a huge red flag in a production system. If you want to keep the clients in sync with server data, look in to using Websockets instead, especially if there are a lot of connected clients. You will cut your network traffic and server load by an order of magnitude, avoiding any potential issues, like the one you've encountered, from ever occurring in the first place.

Comment: @Zak - Yes, I'm afraid so. What it does is prevent **anything** else happening on the page. You don't need anything more to prevent your function overlapping with itself (assuming you don't call `get_activity` anywhere else), because you're not starting the next one until the previous one completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware constantly polling like that. It's generally poor practice. [This article](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/) offers some alternatives.

But to your ajax call:

When you use `async: false`, you make the ajax call **synchronous**, which means that while the network operation is happening, no other JavaScript can run and in most browsers, the page is completely nonresponsive.

Remove the `async: false` and instead use the `success` callback:

```
function get_activity() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/activity.php",
        // *** Use the `success` callback
        success: function(text) {
            $('#activity').html(text);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                get_activity();
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: *(**Oops**, I forgot to remove the `async: false`. Hit refresh if you see it above.)*

Comment: I am a backend developer so the `async` vs `synchro` is a little bit of a thought process change.  Admittedly I am still a little confused by it.  BUT -- I will read on this further and MAKE myself more familiar!  I am going to try this, and I'll accept once I watch the performance for a couple hours.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Zak: You should be able to accelerate your testing by dropping the timeout value for a bit. The end result should be the same.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ - Thanks for the typo fix! (We had overlapping edits.)

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ ^Good call   I'll reduce it to half second and run it for 10 mins ..

Comment: You should consider JSON output - save server and data flow, let client browsers do table creation via JS, just do `json_encode($activity_log)`.

Comment: Didn't even take that long .. Noticeable program improvement right away .. Thank you!

Comment: A back end developers should still know about mutli-threaded vs single-threaded; but may not realise/know that javascript is single-threaded (can only do one thing at a time, such as waiting for a server request)